# PHP and JQuery not working

Tags: php, jquery, drop-down-menu

I have the below code. It is a simple two-step drop down list. The first list is supposed to trigger the second one. I can not figure out why there seems to be no response to selecting something from the first list. I am sure it is something super simple I am missing but I can't seem to figure it out.

Thanks so much.

UPDATE: Just to give a little more info. The variable - $selectvalue loads find and ajax (in the console at least) shows the URL with the GET selectvalue variable. The problem is the second drop down menu does not reflect this even though the HTML output shows it correctly. Also if I load the page with a GET variable manually it works just fine.

```
<?php
$selectvalue = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['svalue']);


?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function($) {
  var list_target_id = 'state-select'; //first select list ID
  var list_select_id = 'installation'; //second select list ID
  var initial_target_html = '<option value="">Please select a colour...</option>'; //Initial prompt for target select

  $('#'+list_target_id).html(initial_target_html); //Give the target select the prompt option

  $('#'+list_select_id).change(function(e) {
    //Grab the chosen value on first select list change
    var selectvalue = $(this).val();

    //Display 'loading' status in the target select list
    $('#'+list_target_id).html('<option value="">Loading...</option>');

    if (selectvalue == "") {
        //Display initial prompt in target select if blank value selected
       $('#'+list_target_id).html(initial_target_html);
    } else {
      //Make AJAX request, using the selected value as the GET
      $.ajax({url: 'index.php?page=search&svalue='+selectvalue,
             success: function(output) {
                //alert(output);
                $('#'+list_target_id).html(output);
            },
          error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(xhr.status + " "+ thrownError);
          }});
        }
    });
});
</script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
        <h3><?php echo $pageName; ?> </h3>
        <?php if ($msgBox) { echo $msgBox; } ?>

        <p>
            Before you commit to a membership, it is best to be sure there is a Scout available in the area you need. Use the search tool below to see available Scouts.
        </p>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="loginCont">
                    <div class='login text-center'>

                        <?php if ($msgBox) { echo $msgBox; } ?>
                        <form method = "post" action="index.php?page=users">
                            <select name="state-select" id="state-select">
                                 <option value="">Please select..</option>
                                 <option value="AL">AL</option>
                                 <option value="AK">AK</option>
                                 <option value="AR">AR</option>
                            </select>
                            <p>
                            <?php


                             $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT installations.name FROM installations WHERE installations.state = '$selectvalue'");


                             echo '<select name="installation" id="installation">';
                             while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { ?>

                                <option value="<?=$row['id']?>"> <? echo $row['name'] ?></option>


                            <?php  }
                             echo '</select>';

                                     $_SESSION['installation_id'] =  $_POST['installation'];


                             mysqli_close($con);
                                ?>
                            </p>
                            <button>Check This Location</button>
                        </form>
```

Comment: Sidenote: If this `<? php` is part or your actual code, remove the space `<?php`.

Comment: Thanks @Fred-ii- It actually is right in my code. I just threw that in when I copied over this portion.

Comment: Got it, had to check. Are short tags set?

Comment: Yes, everything was working fine until I try and implement this. Just doesn't seem to respond to changing that first drop down.

Comment: Anything interesting in javascript console ?

Comment: @Flo made an update, but no errors. Console shows everything to be working?

Answer (score 0):

```
var selectvalue = $(this).val();
```

...should be more like :

```
var selectValue = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
```

Could you give it a try ?

At least try a

```
console.log(selectValue);
```

...before sending the request to be sure.

Comment: I tried this, still same result. The alert(output) shows me this great HTML page with EXACTLY what I need, but then the second drop down won't load and still shows the initial prompt of "Please select a colour..." It's like it just stops loading... nothing from console.log. Thanks for your help. This is the tutorial I have been working with http://www.webdevdoor.com/javascript-ajax/dynamic-select-list-jquery-php/